# Renaming the generated war file in gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am using gradle to generate a war file so that I can directly deploy the war in any remote tomcat server. I want to name the generated war as `ROOT.war` and after going through [the docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:archiveName) I found a way of doing it as:

```
war.archiveName = "ROOT.war"
```

Its working fine but gradle generates the war as `root.war` (the name is in lowercase).

Can you tell me how to convert it into uppercase or is there any better way of doing it?

NOTE: I am using `Gradle 2.2` on `MAC OS X Yosemite`

Comment: I do the same thing, and have no problem. Which version of Gradle? Which OS? I don't see why gradle would transform the name to lowercase. Are you sure it's not your file-system or some other tool?

Comment: Have edited the question which includes further details. Thanks.

Comment: Gradle tries to use the exact name specified, and there aren't any related configuration options. Perhaps your filesystem is case-insensitive?